# What happens if user created data on an iOS device uses up all of the memory on the phone?

Tags: ios, memory

In other words lets say I have an app that allows users to create their own data (like the camera app), what happens when the picture that is taken exceeds the remaining memory on the device ?

Comment: What do you mean by "memory"? Disk space or RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's up to the operating system to handle those situations. Remember, a phone, smart phone, works pretty much like a computer. The same way your computer would notify you that is running out of available space... or an error that can't copy... look into the developer API, there should be a way to handle this exceptions.